# How to style in C# Paragraph like make my string more Bold

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itext

I have a problem. If I create a Paragraph by giving it the value of my string surname, I dont know, how to give this Paragraph style which comes after that into a PDF File with `this -> document.Add(surnameValue);`

```
Paragraph surnameValue = new Paragraph(surname);
```

Comment: With style I mean like make it bold or italic or any style like in CSS for example you can choose everything to stye something...

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if something is not clear !

Comment: @mybirthname it didnt work, I have still same error... doesnt recognize "Font", even I use all namespaces which I included

Answer (score 0):

You can add font like this in iTextSharp:

```
BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
Font times = new Font(bfTimes, 12, Font.BOLD, Color.RED);

Paragraph testP = new Paragraph("This is a Red Font Test using Times Roman", times)
```

**EDIT**

Here [Documentation](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/html/24936b22-0ca8-ba49-d7e5-0615da7c6d1f.htm) about Font.

Comment: Doesn't work :( I become an error, it doesnt recognize the following things which are in the "" to show you:
"Font" times = new "Font"(bfTimes, 12, Font."BOLD", Color."RED");

Comment: @NinjaCoder & mybirthname, you should possibly compare your `import` statements.

Comment: @mybirthname it didnt work, I have still same error... doesnt recognize "Font", even I use all namespaces which I included

Comment: @mkl sry but what u mean. which import statements

Comment: @NinjaCoder I meant the namespace using statements (I was thinking in Java there). I.e. which namespaces *do* you include?

Comment: @mkl These here:
`using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`

Comment: That means you get `Font` both from `System.Drawing` and `iTextSharp.text`. Thus, you have to help your compiler a bit and use the full `iTextSharp.text.Font`: `iTextSharp.text.Font times = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, Color.RED)`. BTW, VS 2013 warns about this. Which is your environment? You might furthermore want to cut down on your namespace `using` statements, with so many of them collisions always are imminent...